# What is a Triple in Java?

Tags: java, object, store

I've come across code that looks like the following:

```
public List<Triple<String, String, Instant>> methodName() {
    // Do something
}
```

What is the `Triple`, how should It be used?

Comment: What package does it import `Triple` from? Just find the Javadoc for that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Triple](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Triple.html) is useful when you want to save 3 values at a time and you can pass different data types. If you just want to learn then below is an example of its usage but if you want to use in code then I would suggest you to use `Objects` instead.

```
public class Triple<T, U, V> {

    private final T first;
    private final U second;
    private final V third;

    public Triple(T first, U second, V third) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
        this.third = third;
    }

    public T getFirst() { return first; }
    public U getSecond() { return second; }
    public V getThird() { return third; }
}
```

And this is how you can instantiate it:

```
List<Triple<String, Integer, Integer>> = new ArrayList<>();
```

**EDIT**

As discussed in comments, please note that it belongs to `org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple` It is not a built-in class in Java.

Comment: Is this more efficient than trying to use a class?

Comment: @cody.tv.weber I don't think its more efficient. I think it is just a convenient class provide by Apache Commons

Comment: So this would be similar to Golang's multiple value return essentially?  Ok, I guess this could be convenient.

Answer (score 3):

Think "tuple" for 3 values!

Many programming languages provide means to efficiently deal with lists of a "fixed" length but different types for each entry.

That Triple class is the Java way of providing you something like that. Like a Pair, but one more entry.

At its core, a fixed length tuple allows you to "loosely couple" multiple values of different types based on some sort of "ordering".

Answer (score 2):

When you need a data structure to deal with a list of three entities, you might use a Triple. Here's a small example:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Triple;
    
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Triple<Integer, String, String>> tripleList = new ArrayList<>();
        tripleList.add(Triple.of(100, "Japan", "Tokyo"));
        tripleList.add(Triple.of(200, "Italy", "Rome"));
        tripleList.add(Triple.of(300, "France", "Paris"));

        for (Triple<Integer, String, String> triple : tripleList) {
            System.out.println("Triple left = " + triple.getLeft());
            System.out.println("Triple right = " + triple.getRight());
            System.out.println("Triple middle = " + triple.getMiddle());
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

> Triple left = 100
> Triple right = Tokyo
> Triple middle = Japan
> Triple left = 200
> Triple right = Rome
> Triple middle = Italy
> Triple left = 300
> Triple right = Paris
> Triple middle = France